# Google Picker API returns 403

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client, google-picker

We have an integration in our app that allows the user the select a folder from their Google Drive using the Google Picker.

All was going well until yesterday and now when trying to open the picker, the app completes oAuth but then returns with 403 [image]

This is a bit strange, I confirmed all keys, clientId, and JS origins and nothing has changed in the app or in the cloud console.

I did however notice that the URL contains `relayURL` and is set to `<protocol>://<domain>/favicon.ico` that is very strange. I used `filePicker.setRelayUrl('<domain>')` ** without  and it works, except now the callback is not fired and there are no console errors or logs.

[image]

Just wondering if there was a change in Google's api.js.

Here is the sample code for building the picker. I am using Angular 8.

```
 //Create the google picker
 this.picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
               .setTitle(`Please select a folder to sync`)
               .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
               .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_DRIVES)
               .setAppId(this.appId)
               .setOAuthToken(this.oauthToken)
               .addView(foldersView)
               .setDeveloperKey(this.developerKey)
               .setOrigin(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host)
               .setRelayUrl(window.location.host)
               .setCallback(this._pickerCallback)
               .build();

  this.picker.setVisible(true);

  private _pickerCallback = (data): void => {
        
        // User has closed the picker
        if (data.action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
            // Do comething when user clicks cancel
        }
        else if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          // Do something when picked
        }
   }
```

Comment: Whats scopes are you using?

Comment: If you did not change anything - sometimes Picker randomly throws 403 for a short time and then works again, otherwise feel free to comment on https://issuetracker.google.com/188179650.

Comment: Just `drive.file` https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file, We have multiple stacks and this has affected our QA, Staging and Production websites, just a bit bizarre, would have expected it to last for an hour or so, but it's broken since yesterday. Will take a look at the issue tracker.

Comment: Check if changing the scope to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly" solves the issue. https://issuetracker.google.com/179397319

Comment: It does not, but regardless of the scope, adding ` .setRelayUrl(window.location.host)` to the pickerBuilder fixes it, but the callback does not work.

Comment: Did you check if Drive SDK Api is authorized on your user's workspace domain ?